# Geocoder - multiple markes won't show title

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, title, marker

I have a problem with geocoder not displaying title for each marker. Here is the code:

```
var map;
var marker = [];
function gmap_initialize() {        
    var ikonica = templateDir+'/images/gmap/gmap_pointer_and_shadow.png';
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('gmap');   
    var my_latlan = new google.maps.LatLng(45.55496, 18.69551);
    var map_options = {
        center: my_latlan,
        zoom: 13,     
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(gmap, map_options);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //js_adrese below is actually an array that contains addresses  
    for (i=0; i<js_adrese.length; i++)
    {           
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': js_adrese[i]}, function(results, status) {        
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {               
            var x = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var y = results[0].geometry.location.lng();             
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({                    
               position: results[0].geometry.location,
               map: map,                   
               icon: ikonica,
               title: js_adrese[i] // undefined in console
            });             
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Geocode failed. Reason: " + status);
        }
    });     
}
};
```

When I do manage to show the title, it only displays the last value of js_adrese[i], so each marker has a same title.

Important: I am a total noob in js and google api, so please, if you would be kind enough to lower the tech talk to my idiotic level and point out in lame terms, what is the problem and how to solve it? Please

Comment: I've had this problem too, maybe you can try a different Geocoding Service, see here some alternatives http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/06/21/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Closure with google.maps.Geocoder::geocode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171664/javascript-closure-with-google-maps-geocodergeocode?rq=1)

Comment: I've separated everything into its own function and it worked... thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps geocode service (personal) only allows 10 requests per second or something close to that.  Try decreasing your request to say 2 or 3 addresses, and if that works correctly then you'd have to geocode offline and create your markers from the generated lat and longs.